# expect usage in bash script or bash command in expect script

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

I have a script below that works except for the expect portion:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
invdir=/home/john/inventory

for file in $invdir/$1
do
  if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ]
  then
     echo "You must enter a value: prod, dev, dr, or test AND the password of the env you entered"
     exit 0
  else
      for host in `cat $file`
      do
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $host <<-EOF
    expect "password:"
    send "$2\n" 
    EOF
      done
  fi
done
```

I found an expect script that does most of what I need:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh-copy-id $argv
expect "password:"
send "your_password\n"
expect eof

to execute ./expect_script user@host1
```

My problem is that I don't know enough of either bash or expect to get these two to work under one bash script or expect script.

Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
invdir=/home/john/inventory

for file in "$invdir"/"$1"
do
  if [[ -z "$1" ]] || [[ -z "$2" ]]
  then
    echo "You must enter a value: prod, dev, dr, or test AND the password of the env you entered"
    exit 0
  else
    while IFS= read -r host
    do
      export host
      export pw="$2"
      expect <<'EOF'

        spawn ssh-copy-id -i $env(HOME)/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $env(host)
        expect "password:"
        send "$env(pw)\n" 
        expect eof

EOF
    done < "$file"
  fi
done
```

Some notes:

- take care to quote your shell variables, especially positional params
- you need to launch the expect interpreter to run expect code
- pass shell variables to expect via the environment
- [don't read the lines of a file with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
- I don't use `<<-EOF` because it's too easy to use non-tabs for the EOF word.
- but do use `<<'EOF'` to protect the expect variables

Comment: hi Glenn,
Thank you for the answer and suggestions. When I ran the new script, it's giving me the following errors:
`./new-ssh-login.sh prod mypasswd`
`invalid command name "ssh-copy-id"
    while executing
"ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $env(host)"`

Comment: D'oh! I forgot to use the crucial expect `spawn` command to launch the process we're going to control. Fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head that expect understands `~` , so I used the HOME environment variable instead.

Comment: Thanks Glenn.  the scripts works now!!!  I do have 2 questions.
1. how does the line `while IFS= read -r host` translate to $file (as this is what it looks like it's doing.
2. the line `done < "$file"` is this FEEDING the while loop 

Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Yes that's right. We're redirecting the contents of the file into the while loop, and the `read` command then consumes the input line-by-line. Explained in detail at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: hi Glenn,
One more favor.  How can I ping the host and if it pings, go onto the spawn ssh-copy-id command else goto the next host.  I'm just not sure how to put this in the script.
Thanks again.

Comment: Ask a separate question.